# Getting a margin on HTML Table images

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

I'm not sure where this extra spacing is coming from for this email blast. really a problem when it's one image per a row, but when it's multiple it's throwing things out of wack
[image]

I've been experimenting for awhile trying to remove it, but can't figure it out

```html
    <html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"   style="table-layout: fixed; margin: 0px auto; ">
       <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="5" valign="center">
         <a href="https://www.lasvegasnow.com/open-enrollment-forum"><img src="https://media.lasvegasnow.com/nxsglobal/lasvegasnow/photo/2018/10/05/header_1538749577392_57983134_ver1.0.jpg" style = "display: block; width: 600px;"></a>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="5">
         <img src="https://media.lasvegasnow.com/nxsglobal/lasvegasnow/photo/2018/10/05/fbl_1538747453659_57975885_ver1.0.jpg" style = "display: block; width: 600px;">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <img src="https://media.lasvegasnow.com/nxsglobal/lasvegasnow/photo/2018/10/05/3_1_1538747262360_57975876_ver1.0.jpg" style = "display: block; width: 90px; height: 34px;">
        </td>
        <td align="center" colspan="1">
         <img src="https://media.lasvegasnow.com/nxsglobal/lasvegasnow/photo/2018/10/05/btn1_1538747262364_57975877_ver1.0.jpg" style = "display: block; width: 153px; height: 34px;">
        </td>
        <td align="center" colspan="1">
         <img src="https://media.lasvegasnow.com/nxsglobal/lasvegasnow/photo/2018/10/05/3_2_1538747263511_57975878_ver1.0.jpg" style = "display: block; width: 109px; height: 34px;">
        </td>
        <td align="center" colspan="1">
         <img src="https://media.lasvegasnow.com/nxsglobal/lasvegasnow/photo/2018/10/05/btn2_1538747263651_57975879_ver1.0.jpg" style = "display: block; width: 155px; height: 34px;">
        </td>
        <td align="center" colspan="1">
         <img src="https://media.lasvegasnow.com/nxsglobal/lasvegasnow/photo/2018/10/05/3_3_1538747264518_57975880_ver1.0.jpg" style = "display: block; width: 93px; height: 34px;">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4">
         <img src="email_blast_04.jpg" style = "display: block; width: 600px;">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4">
         <img src="email_blast_05.jpg" style = "display: block; width: 600px;">
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4">
         <img src="email_blast_06.jpg" style = "display: block; width: 600px;">
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you post the code that is producing this? That will help others diagnose your problem :)

Comment: It's on there. I had it on there originally, but hit something to delete it when i originally posted it

Comment: Is there any CSS that you can post that goes along with this? Or is it just pure HTML? Also, the code snippet is not finding a few of your images which is still making it tough to diagnose.

Comment: There's no CSS. I'll edit the  snippet

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, those margins are coming from the image above the two blocks. Try loading the image only in your html with a white background and you will see it. `https://media.lasvegasnow.com/nxsglobal/lasvegasnow/photo/2018/10/05/fbl_1538747453659_57975885_ver1.0.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <head></head>
<body>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"   style="table-layout: fixed; margin: 0px auto; ">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="5" valign="center">
                <a href="https://www.lasvegasnow.com/open-enrollment-forum"><img src="header.jpg" style = "display: block; width: 600px;"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="5">
                <img src="https://media.lasvegasnow.com/nxsglobal/lasvegasnow/photo/2018/10/05/fbl_1538747453659_57975885_ver1.0.jpg" style = "display: block; width: 600px;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <img src="https://media.lasvegasnow.com/nxsglobal/lasvegasnow/photo/2018/10/05/3_1_1538747262360_57975876_ver1.0.jpg" style = "display: block; width: 90px; height: 34px;">
            </td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1">
                <img src="https://media.lasvegasnow.com/nxsglobal/lasvegasnow/photo/2018/10/05/btn1_1538747262364_57975877_ver1.0.jpg" style = "display: block; width: 153px; height: 34px;">
            </td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1">
                <img src="https://media.lasvegasnow.com/nxsglobal/lasvegasnow/photo/2018/10/05/3_2_1538747263511_57975878_ver1.0.jpg" style = " width: 51px; height: 34px;">
            </td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1">
                <img src="https://media.lasvegasnow.com/nxsglobal/lasvegasnow/photo/2018/10/05/btn2_1538747263651_57975879_ver1.0.jpg" style = "display: block; width: 155px; height: 34px;margin-right: 23px;">
            </td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1">
                <img src="https://media.lasvegasnow.com/nxsglobal/lasvegasnow/photo/2018/10/05/3_3_1538747264518_57975880_ver1.0.jpg" style = "display: block; width: 93px; height: 34px;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="4">
                <img src="email_blast_04.jpg" style = "display: block; width: 600px;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="4">
                <img src="email_blast_05.jpg" style = "display: block; width: 600px;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="4">
                <img src="email_blast_06.jpg" style = "display: block; width: 600px;">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: there are very minimal white space due to image which are used are having white spaces may be very minute.. you can try using some more image....

Comment: Hope this is the answer you are looking for

Comment: It looks better, but I'm still seeing margin around images. What changes did you make?

Comment: I have added margin-right to the image which you have used to the right most side and removed 'display : block ' from the centre td which contains a white image.. And if you are asking about the image which is been seen its due to the image "https://media.lasvegasnow.com/nxsglobal/lasvegasnow/photo/2018/10/05/fbl_1538747453659_57975885_ver1.0.jpg" If you see this image it has margin in the bottom if you can get some image which doesn't have those margin you will not get this issue as such